# jQuery Mobile - How to check for page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm currently building a simple jQuery Mobile application. Currently, if I want to do some stuff either before or after page load, I use the following call hook:

When page is shown (e.g. to insert data/templates):

```
$(window).on('pageshow', function() {
        if ($('#pageId').length > 0) {

            doStuff();

        }
});
```

If the user moves to a new page (and I want to save some values):

```
$(document).delegate('#pageId #buttonNext', 'click', function() {
    doStuff();
});
```

I have two questions:

Is there a better and more elegant way to do this (and I am sure there is)?
On mobile devices (especially iOS Safari) each time the app is re-opened after safari has been closed, the `pageshow` method is fired again so for example are re-entered into the already fully built up page. Is there a way to prevent that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want a event that will trigger only once and a better way to save some values during the page transition.

There are several page events that will trigger only once during the app life, it doesn't matter if page is visited several times.

First two to mention are **[pagebeforecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforecreate/)** and **[pagecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)**, those two events will trigger only once before and during the page creation. This is also an excellent opportunity to add dynamically generated content because jQuery Mobile will enhance its content a little bit further down the line.

Third page event is called **[pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)** and it a real counterpart to classic jQuery document ready. Like previous 2 events mentioned it will trigger only once but this is also a moment when jQuery Mobile content is about to be enhanced, so every dynamic content added at this point must be **[manually enhanced](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**. This event is also excellent for event binding, because unlike **[pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)**, when binding events in **`pageinit`** you don't need to worry about multiple event binding.

**`Pageshow`** should be used ONLY when working with plugins that require correct page height because page height has real value only when page is shown. This is important for plugins like photo galleries, carousels, basically everything that handles pictures.

If you want to find more about page events take a look [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/). Also there you will be able to find 3 different solutions of passing / storing data between page transitions.

Comment: @gajotres, in what event would you fetch dynamic content?

Comment: If this is the first page then I would use pageinit, in any other case I would fetch it on a previous page, show ajax loader and initiate pagechange when content is successfully loaded into the DOM.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Both these functions have been deprecated in 1.4.0 in favor of pagecreate and pagecontainer widget's pagecontainerchange event. 

You should update your article http://www.gajotres.net/advanced-jquery-mobile-tutorial-part-3-dynamic-content/ to reflect this. Great article by the way :)

Comment: I'm not using them, pagecontainer is still not fully implemented, at least not properly. And tnx :)

Comment: Yes you are :-) ->  `$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ `

Comment: I meant I'm not using new pagecontainer events.